# Remove spaces at beginning of each array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've had to `split()` a large string into an array, whatever way it worked I'm now left with a space before each element.

For example:

```
var array = [" hello"," goodbye"," no"];
```

How can I get rid of this?

Split code as requested:

```
var depots = v.innerHTML.split(',');
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```js
var array = [" hello"," goodbye"," no"];
array = array.map(function (el) {
  return el.trim();
});
console.log(array);
```

if you use `ES2015`, you can do it shorter, with arrow function

```
array = array.map(el => el.trim());
```

Answer (score 11):

**Don't use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change each element in the array,** when you can remove the spaces from the string itself when splitting it by a delimiter.

Use [`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) with [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) with RegEx

```
str.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/)
```

The regex `\s*,\s*` will match comma surrounded by any number(*including zero*) of spaces.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var regex = /\s*,\s*/;

document.getElementById('textbox').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.value.trim().split(regex));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

`trim()` will remove the leading and trailing spaces from the string and `split` with the RegEx `,\s*` will split the string by comma followed by any number of spaces.

The same results can also be achieved using the negated RegEx with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Match) with global flag.

```
str.match(/[^,\s]+/g)
```

---

> Why `map()` should not be used?

Using `map` in this case requires extra overheads. First, `split` the string by `,` and then iterate over each of the element of the array and remove the leading and trailing spaces using `trim` and then updating the array. This is bit slower than using the `split` with above RegEx.

Comment: what about this case `"test,test,test, ff  ff, ffdf d  ,  df".trim().split(/,\s*/)`

Comment: @Alexander Works perfect! What OP want? --> `v.innerHTML.split(',');` and then `How can I get rid of spaces?` The above gave me output `["test", "test", "test", "ff ff", "ffdf d ", "df"]` which is what OP wants.

Comment: not perfect `"ffdf d "` - as you can see there is space after `d`. anyway I've written in comment to author to look at your solution, I think it is good, however need to know what author wants.

Comment: @Alexander Not sure why you said _Not perfect_ for that input. I've added live demo, check the string above in the demo.

Comment: @Tushar you have changed `RegExp` from `/,\s*/` to `/\s*,\s*/`!

Comment: @Alexander Yes, found a minor bug when creating demo.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [" hello"," goodbye"," no"].toString().replace(/\s*\,\s*/g, ",").trim().split(",");

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue in Tushar's Answer

Just one more thing to add in [@Tushar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903863/remove-spaces-at-beginning-of-each-array-element/34904446#34904446) answer.
Answer is great and well explained. One thing just missed that I think  it's not question's requirement.

If user enter double comma instead of single in result an empty string will be added/return into the array. I just did a little change to the code.

```
.filter(elem => elem.length !== 0)
```

#### Explaination

[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) iterate into each element of the array and check if it is empty or not by String's [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property. If an element length will not be equal to zero it will be added/return as element into array. And at the last a brand new filtered array will be returned.

```js
var regex = /\s*,\s*/;

document.getElementById('textbox').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.value.trim().split(regex).filter(elem => elem.length !== 0));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through each array element and trim it . As like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    trimmedArray[i] = array[i].trim();
```

Answer (score -5):

**You need these two jQuery functions:**

1.) iterate through array element with ability to edit items:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

2.) remove blank spaces from beginning and end of a string:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

**Use them this way:**

```
array = $.map(array, function(value) { return value.trim();});
```

**Check this JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/L00eyL4x/49/